# Why using %c for formatting instead of %d

Tags: c, printf

This is code for To find sum of two numbers without using any operator,here why they are used %c instead of %d ? What is the features of %c compare to %d ?

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return printf("%*c%*c",  x, ' ',  y, ' ');
}

int main()
{
    printf("Sum = %d", add(3, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `%d` instead and see what happen

Comment: The top answer on the duplicate is wrong >.>

Answer (score 1):

Here this is utilizing the return value of `printf`. Respectively `x-1` spaces(`' '`) and then again space (as you specified) and  `y-1` blanks and then again 1 space is being printed. And then the total number of characters written is returned. That is how the sum is being done.

I just remember this rule

```
printf("%*c",X,C) prints the char C in a field of size X
```

All these behavior is explained in C11 Standard.

From standard  **[§7.21.6.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4)**

> An optional minimum field width. ***If the converted value has fewer
>   characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces (by default)***
>   on the left (or right, if the left adjustment flag, described later,
>   has been given) to the field width. *The field width takes the form of
>   an asterisk `*` (described later) or a nonnegative decimal integer.*

And in the same section  **[§7.21.6.1p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p5)**

> As noted above, ***a field width, or precision, or both, may be
>   indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an int argument supplies the
>   field width or precision***

At last [**§7.21.6.1.p14**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p14)

> ***The `fprintf` function returns the number of characters transmitted***, or
>   a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

### Why `%c` instead of `%d`?

One can argue that it is because it is not our intention to print those numbers or anything - it is just to `print` `x` number of something and `y` number of something so that we get the rturn value of `x+y`. You can try this and this one will also work but you will see some numbers in the screen with so large field witdh. Try this

```
 return printf("%*d%*d",  x, x,  y, y);
```

If `x = 10` and `y=2` then it will be

```
| | | | | | | | |1|0| |2|
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 \ \
                      11 12

That's how 12 characters are printed.
```

Comment: super .Thanks a lot @coderredoc

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Note two things here:

`printf("%*c",x,' ')` specifies a width of `x` for printing `' '`

`printf()` returns the character count.

So

```
return printf("%*c%*c",  x, ' ',  y, ' ');
```

returns total characters printed which is -

width specified to print `' '` which is `x` + width specified to print `' '` which is `y` which is equivalent to returning `x+y`